# Regex to find decimal or non decimal number on same or next line in java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text

```
My thing 0.02
My thing 100.2
My thing 65
My thing
0.03
My thing
13
My thing
    45.67 stuff
```

I want to extract the 'My thing' and the number associated with it can split it and put it into an map (I know the keys will over-wreite each other in this example- its just the example Im using here- My thing will actually be incorporated into its own map so it isn't an issue)

```
Mything=0.02,Mything=100.2,Mything=65,Mything=0.03,Mything=13,Mything=45.67
```

I tried

```
 Pattern match_pattern = Pattern.compile(start.trim()+"\\n.*?\\d*\\.\\d*\\s",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

but this doesn't quite do what I want

Comment: sorry. start is an imported string. It is correct. I read line by line from a text file to make the matches so start refers to each line imported to make the match

Comment: Then please share the relevant code you have to get the whole picture.

Comment: Do you mean numbers with and without a decimal point? Really this indiscrimate use of 'decimal' to mean absolutely anything about a number has got to stop.

Comment: Yes with and without a decimal point

Comment: I confused the tags, sorry. Still, what you are doing is not logical: you read line by line, and then use a regex to search some text *across lines*. That is bound to fail.

Comment: The pattern for an integer or decimal might be `\d+(\.\d+)?` so if you want to look for `start` followed by that number and optional whitespace in between you might try the pattern `start + "\\s*\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"` (line breaks are whitespace as well) and apply the pattern to multiline text (i.e. don't apply it to individual lines). If there can be anything in between (not just whitespace) you'll want to use `.*` along with the DOT_ALL flag instead of `\s*`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Please post as an answer- that worked. so the brackets followed by ? means optional I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern for an integer or decimal might be `\d+(\.\d+)?` so if you want to look for `start` followed by that number and optional whitespace in between you might try the pattern `start + "\\s*\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"` (line breaks are whitespace as well) and apply the pattern to multiline text (i.e. don't apply it to individual lines). If there can be anything in between (not just whitespace) you'll want to use `.*` along with the DOT_ALL flag instead of `\s*`.

Breakdown of the expression `start + "\\s*\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"`

- `start` contains a subexpression which is provided from elsewhere. If you want to make sure it is treated as a literal (i.e. special characters like `*` etc. are not interpreted wrap it with `\Q` and `\E`, i.e. `"\\Q" + start + "\\E"`)
- `\s*` (or `\\s*` in a Java string literal) means "any whitespace" which also includes line breaks
- `\d+(\.\d+)?` (or `\\d+(\\.\\d+)?` in a Java string literal) means "one or more digits followed by zero or one group consisting of a dot and one or more digits" - this means the "dot and one or more digits" part is optional but if there is a dot it must be followed by at least one digit.

Additional note: if you want to access the capturing groups e.g. to extract the number you'll want to use a non-capturing group for the optional part and wrap the entire (sub-)expression in a capturing group, e.g. `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`. In that case, if you'd use `Pattern` and `Matcher`, you could access the number using `group(1)` - or if you wrap `start` in a group as well (like `"(\\Q" + start + "\\E)\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)"`) you'd get the first part as `group(1)` and the second part as `group(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to extract the *records* you could do it like

```
    String s = "My thing 0.02\nMy thing 100.2\nMy thing 65\nMy thing\n"+
                "0.03\nMy thing\n13\nMy thing\n    45.67 stuff\n";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(My thing)\\s*(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)").matcher(s);
```

Then loop through the matches and add to the dictionary, or what ever... ;)

```
    while (m.find()) {
        // Add to dictionary, group 1 is key, 2 is value
        System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(0)+ ":" + m.group(1)+":" + m.group(2));
    }
```

[See it here at ideone](https://ideone.com/qpDT8o).